# Loading data from Spark into Snowflake

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load data from spark into snowflake. Does the load to snowflake utilizes spark engine or its completely pushdown to snowflake ?

Thanks,
Naveed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Snowflake does, in part, leverage Spark's distributed execution engine.

As of early 2020, writes from Spark using the Snowflake connector [happen in two basic stages](https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake/blob/3029f1b9e341a10ab7f1fc14b2e02a93c8e959e4/src/main/scala/net/snowflake/spark/snowflake/SnowflakeWriter.scala#L34-L49).

First, the dataset is written out in an ideal file size and format (`CSV` by default, but it uses `JSON` if your dataset fields [include variant types](https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake/blob/3029f1b9e341a10ab7f1fc14b2e02a93c8e959e4/src/main/scala/net/snowflake/spark/snowflake/SnowflakeWriter.scala#L57-L59)) onto a cloud-based storage (`S3`, `WASB`, etc.) location [automatically defined](https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake/blob/65648c642c87924491d9d059fe0e7494afc6a4a2/src/main/scala/net/snowflake/spark/snowflake/io/CloudStorageOperations.scala#L277-L280) as a [stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html), and this occurs [as a distributed step leveraging Spark's execution engine](https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake/blob/69c2466253039609809ecfa7325014fab594a230/src/main/scala/net/snowflake/spark/snowflake/io/CloudStorageOperations.scala#L681-L716).

Next, a [`COPY INTO` statement](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html) is used to [load the files uploaded to the stage](https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake/blob/af818082cfde3d4b4f760e94815cdcbfe65fa450/src/main/scala/net/snowflake/spark/snowflake/io/StageWriter.scala#L124-L142) into the target Snowflake table.

Answer (score 0):

> The Spark Connector applies predicate and query pushdown by capturing
>   and analyzing the Spark logical plans for SQL operations. When the
>   data source is Snowflake, the operations are translated into a SQL
>   query and then executed in Snowflake to improve performance.
>
> However, because this translation requires almost a one-to-one
>   translation of Spark SQL operators to Snowflake expressions, not all
>   of Spark SQL operators can be pushed down. When pushdown fails, the
>   connector falls back to a less-optimized execution plan. The
>   unsupported operations are instead performed in Spark.